# Entity Framework 6 Multiple Datacontext Sharing a transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

```
using(var Db = new Framework_DbContext())
{
    var DbContextTransaction = Db.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
    using (var db = new DocumentLibDbContext())
    {
        //**How to use the above DbContextTransaction？？**
        db.Database.UseTransaction(DbContextTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction);
    ｝
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify whether your contexts connect to the same database or not.

If the databases are different, you need to avoid `BeginTransaction` and `UseTransaction`and instread wrap your code in a `TransactionScope`.

Assuming they both connect to the same database, you don't specify whether you are using an EDMX or Code First. I had the same problem using EDMX, spent the whole day with trial and error and finally came up with a solution.

```
var workspace = new MetadataWorkspace(new[] { "res://*/" }, new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.;initial catalog=MultpleEdmxTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"))
{
    using (var entityConnection1 = new EntityConnection(workspace, connection, false))
    {
        using (var entityConnection2 = new EntityConnection(workspace, connection, false))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (var schema1Entities = new Schema1Entities(entityConnection1))
                {
                    schema1Entities.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
                    // code goes here
                    schema1Entities.SaveChanges();
                }

                using (var schema2Entities = new Schema2Entities(entityConnection2))
                {
                    schema2Entities.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
                    // code goes here
                    schema2Entities.SaveChanges();
                }
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You define the extra constructors in partial classes like so:

```
partial class Schema1Entities
{
    public Schema1Entities(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, false) { }
}
```

where false indicates that you open and close the connection manually.

As a bonus you now only need one connection string in your config and it doesn't include all the useless EF junk that normally comes with it (metadata=res://*/blabla).